# Unknown compiler error in Java, I think it's an issue of scope

Tags: java, compiler-errors, scope

I'm making an implementation of Breadth-First and Depth-First search for class and I am getting an error when compiling that I can't understand. The error is:

> symbol  : variable aList
>   location: class java.lang.Object for(graphNode node: map.get(i).aList){

The aList variable is a TreeSet that is stored in every node containing whatever nodes that node is attached to in the corresponding graph. I use the exact same syntax in the main method above and it doesn't give any errors. Also, when I printed out all the nodes from the map in the traverse method, it printed the integer keys, not the graphNode values that it should have. I'm just very confused right now. Thanks for any help.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class HW1 {

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
    sc.useDelimiter("(\\s)"); // divide up by whitespcae

    TreeMap<Integer, graphNode> map = new TreeMap<Integer, graphNode>();
    int totalNodes = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
    int totalEdges = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());

    // Fill up the map with nodes
    for(int i = 1; i <= totalNodes ; i++) {
        map.put(i, new graphNode(i, null, 10000));

    }

   // Add all the edges to the adjacency list
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        int start = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        int end = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
         graphNode startNode = map.get(start);
         graphNode endNode = map.get(end);

         if(!startNode.aList.contains(endNode)){
            startNode.aList.add(endNode);
         }
         if(!endNode.aList.contains(startNode)){
            endNode.aList.add(startNode); 
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= map.size(); i++){
        for(graphNode node: map.get(i).aList){
            System.out.print(node.value+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    } 

    traverse(map);

}

public static void traverse(TreeMap map){

        for(int i = 1; i <= map.size(); i++){
            for(graphNode node: map.get(i).aList){
                System.out.print(node.value+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        } 

}

}
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class graphNode implements Comparable<graphNode> {
int value;
int distance;
graphNode prev;
TreeSet<graphNode> aList;
String color;


public graphNode(int value, graphNode prev, int distance) {
    this.value = value;
    this.prev = prev;
    this.distance = distance;
    aList = new TreeSet<graphNode>();
    String color = "white";
}

public String toString() {
    return value + "";
}

public int compareTo(graphNode other) {
    if (this.value < other.value){
        return -1;
    }else if (this.value == other.value){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Post the *exact* and *complete* error message, and tell us which line it refers to.

Comment: HW1.java:61: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable aList
location: class java.lang.Object
           for(graphNode node: map.get(i).aList){
                                         ^
1 error

Comment: You error is occuring on one of these lines - `for(graphNode node: map.get(i).aList){`. Whatever kind of object you have in that map, you're going to want to put an accessor method for the list on it and use that instead `whateverObj.getList()`, instead of `map.get(i).aList`.

Comment: There is nothing unknown about a 'cannot find symbol' error.

Answer (score 8):

In `main`, `map` is a

```
TreeMap<Integer, graphNode> map = new TreeMap<Integer, graphNode>();
```

but in `traverse`, it is just a `TreeMap`. So there `get(i)` returns an `Object`, and not a `graphNode`.

An `Object` has no `aList` field.

Declare

```
public static void traverse(TreeMap<Integer, graphNode> map){
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `traverse()` method, the map is declared as `TreeMap map`. So you're using the raw (non-generic) TreeMap type, and the compiler doesn't know the type of the keys and values stored in the map. All it knows is that they're Object instances.

Declare the map as `TreeMap<Integer, graphNode>` or even `Map<Integer, graphNode>`, and everything will be fine.

And while you're at it, rename `graphNode` to `GraphNode`. Classes start with an upper-case letter in Java.